# Como concatenar um comando SQL dentro de uma MySQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: php, mysql

Na mostra a seguir, temos um exemplo já rodando em PHP.
O cenário da questão é a montagem de um "link de navegação" baseado numa estrutura de dados.

```php
$node = '006002009';  // Esta informação é obtida dinamicamente.

$segmentos = strlen($node)/3;
$sql = 'SELECT ACESSO_SCRIPT FROM ACESSO_ADMIN WHERE ACESSO_NIVEL';
$or = '';
```

### Loop de concatenação do comando SQL

```php
for($x = 0; $x < $segmentos; $x++){  
$comp = $x+1;  
$sql.= $OR.'="'.substr($node,0,($indent*$comp)).'" ';  
$or = ' OR ACESSO_NIVEL';  
}
```

O resultado do loop gera a string:

```sql
SELECT ACESSO_SCRIPT FROM ACESSO_ADMIN WHERE ACESSO_NIVEL="006" OR ACESSO_NIVEL="006002" OR ACESSO_NIVEL="006002009"`
```

O desafio é conseguir a mesma concatenação do loop acima, dentro da Stored Procedure.
Lembrando que a SP receberia como parâmetro apenas o valor de `$node`. Esse valor é de comprimento variável e segue uma regra de composição em segmentos de 3 algarismos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Acho que algo assim deva resolver seu problema:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE batata(node CHAR(30))
BEGIN
    DECLARE segmentos INT;
    DECLARE jump INT;
    DECLARE contador INT;

    SET segmentos = LENGTH(node) / 3;
    SET jump = segmentos;
    SET contador = 1;

    SET @sql = 'SELECT ACESSO_SCRIPT FROM ACESSO_ADMIN WHERE ACESSO_NIVEL=';
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, '"', node, '"', ' ');

    WHILE contador < segmentos DO
        SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, 'OR ACESSO_NIVEL=', '"', SUBSTR(node, 1, jump), '"', ' ');

        SET contador = contador + 1;
        SET jump = jump * contador;
    END WHILE;

    PREPARE STMT FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE STMT;
END
```

---

Update:

Quanto a lógica não tem segredo está sendo utilizado o mesmo esquema que o do exemplo.
Criei uma procedure que espera uma variável que será chamada de 'node' do tipo char(30) (se precisar de uma string maior basta aumentar esse número)

Dentro da procedure tem 4 variaveis

**segmento** que vai calcular o número de segmentos do 'node' (node/3)
**jump** variavel usada para pegar parte do conteúdo da string com substr
**contador** pra fazer o controle do loop while
e **sql** que vai conter a string da SQL

apos setar o conteúdo inicial do @sql (SET @sql = 'SELECT ACESSO_SCRIPT FROM ACESSO_ADMIN WHERE ACESSO_NIVEL=';)

vou utilizando o comando do mysql CONCAT para concatenar as string de acordo com a lógica necessária.

Após o loop a query sql estará completa,

ai bastar preparar o statement a partir da variável @sql e executar

```
PREPARE STMT FROM @sql;
EXECUTE STMT;
```

se quiser debugar e ver a string basta apagar as linhas `prepare ...` e `execute ...` e por `select @sql;`

Comment: Já vi que está correto e percebi, mas se pudesses explicar num resumo os passos que fizeste a pergunta ficava mais completa.

Comment: Simplesmente perfeito.

Comment: @HumbertoWilsonRondeico que bom que lhe ajudou se puder marque a resposta como solução para seu problema